# Calculation and multiple joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**1.products (Products Table)**

```
1.productid 

  001         
  002         
  003         

2.productname

  x
  y
  z
```

**2.invoiceqty (InvoiceQuantity Table)**

```
1.productid

  001       
  001      
  002       
  002 

2.invqty

  10
  20
  10
  05
```

**3.grnqty (GRN Quantity Table)**

```
1.productid 

  001        
  002        
  003        

2.grqty

  50
  50
  50
```

**4.returninqty (Return In Quantity Table)**

```
1.productid 

  002
  002

2.retinqty

  02
  03
```

**5.returnoutqty (Return Out Quantity Table)**

```
1.productid 

  001
  001

2.retoutqty

  01
  01
```

I need to perform this query to view stock balance
stockbalance calculation like this

(grnqty+returninqty)-(invoiceqty+returnoutqty) = StockBalance

Please Tell me how to write a query for calculating stock balance like this
i have develop a inventory control system in java/MySQL please help me on this query

**6.Stocks(QUERY)**

```
1.productid 

  001
  002
  003

2.Stockqty

  40
  33
  50
```

Comment: Are you stuck on a query that is not returning the expected result or are you simply looking for a statement that will do what you describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is according to your formula but the result you displayed is not produced because i think your formula may have any problem

```
SELECT
  p.productid,

  (ifnull(g.g_sum,0) + ifnull(rq.rq_sum,0))-(ifnull(i.i_sum,0) + ifnull(ro.ro_sum,0)) as StockBalance,

  ifnull(g.g_sum,0) as GRN_QUANTITY,
 ifnull( rq.rq_sum,0) as RETURN_IN_QUANTITY,
 ifnull( i.i_sum,0) as INVENTORY_QUANTITY,
 ifnull( ro.ro_sum,0) as RETURN_OUT_QUANTITY
from products as p
  left join (select
           productid,
           sum(grnqty)  as g_sum
         from grnqty group by productid) as g
    on g.productid = p.productid
  left join (select
           productid,
           sum(retinqty) as rq_sum
         from returninqty group by productid) as rq
    on rq.productid = p.productid
  left join (select
           productid,
           sum(invqty)  as i_sum
         from invoiceqty group by productid) as i
    on i.productid = p.productid
  left join (select
           productid,
           sum(retoutqty) as ro_sum
         from returnoutqty group by productid) as ro
    on ro.productid = p.productid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr raheel shan! its work.. Thank you very much, We need your help more.. Thanks again..

Comment: as far as mysql is concerned i am available

Answer (score 2):

Try to compute the quantities for each table using a subquery. It doesn't work with LEFT JOINs because we would have a cartesian product across the tables.

```
SELECT
    p.productid,
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(grnqty), 0) 
    FROM grnqty g 
    WHERE g.productid = p.productid
) 
 +
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(returninqty), 0) 
    FROM returninqty ri 
    WHERE ri.productid = p.productid
)     
 - 
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(invoiceqty), 0) 
    FROM invoiceqty i 
    WHERE i.productid = p.productid
)
 -
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(returnoutqty), 0) 
    FROM returnoutqty ro 
    WHERE ro.productid = p.productid
) as stock

FROM products p
```

Also, you could create a function to compute the stock. You could easily reuse it for other queries.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `get_product_stock` (IN p_id_product INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

DECLARE stock INT;

SET stock =
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(grnqty), 0)
        FROM grnqty
        WHERE productid = p_id_product
    )
     +
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(returninqty), 0)
        FROM returninqty
        WHERE productid = p_id_product
    )
     -
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(invoiceqty), 0)
        FROM invoiceqty
        WHERE productid = p_id_product
    )
     -
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(returnoutqty), 0)
        FROM returnoutqty
        WHERE productid = p_id_product
    );

RETURN stock;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can use the function like this:

```
// get the stock for product with id 1
SELECT get_product_stock(1); 

// get all the products with their stock
SELECT productid, name, get_product_stock(productid) as stock FROM products;
```

Comment: You're right, I believe the sums are not working because we are grouping by id product and we have a cartesian product among all those table. I will update my answer

Comment: @Rajive You're welcome. I am sorry I didn't give a good solution the first time.